# Destroying instance of AVPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, avplayer

I have a standard `UITableView` with a custom `HeaderView`

In the custom `HeaderView` for the tableview, I have 2 buttons.

```
@interface HeaderView : UIView

UIButton *buttonforDataFeed1;
UIButton *buttonforDataFeed2;
```

When each button is pressed, it is reloads the tableview with data from a different API.

```
-(void) didPressUserButton {
    self.userOrVideoString = @"User";
    [self loadObjects];

}

-(void) didPressVideoButton {
    self.userOrVideoString = @"video";
    [self loadObjects];

}
```

One data feed pulls videos. The other just pulls strings. When I press the video button, the videos appear in my tableview for every cell. When I press my string button, they appear as well.

The problem is that the videos don't die, they stay alive and bunch together on the screen when the other button is tapped.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    if([self.userOrVideoString isEqualToString:@"video"]) {
        VideoCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[VideoCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        NSString *dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:object.updatedAt
                                                              dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle
                                                              timeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];


        PFFile *file = [object objectForKey:@"videoFile"];
        Video *vid = [Video videoWithStringURL:file.url];
        [cell setDelegate:self];

        //problem - i can create videos here but i can't destroy them later
        [cell setVideo:vid];
        [cell play];
        return cell;
    }
    else {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        NSString *username = [object objectForKey:@"username"];
        cell.textLabel.text = username ;
        return cell;
    }

}
```

How do I destroy all of these instances of `AVPlayer`? For reference, here is the custom `VideoCell`

```
@interface VideoCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) AVPlayer *videoPlayer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayerLayer *videoLayer;
```

and the setVideo function

```
- (void)setVideo:(Video *)video
{
    NSLog(@"%s : %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, video);

    //[self generateImageFromAsset:video];
    //[self.videoView addSubview:self.placeholder];

    [self.videoPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:video.video]];
    [self.videoPlayer setActionAtItemEnd:AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone];
    self.videoLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.videoPlayer];
    [self.videoLayer setPlayer:self.videoPlayer];
    [self.videoLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [self.videoView.layer addSublayer:self.videoLayer];
    self.videoPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:[self.videoPlayer currentItem]];

    // Here we add an KVO to the player to know when the video is ready to play
    // This is important if you want the user to see something while the video is being loaded
    [self.videoPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];

    // Here we need to add the indicator to the video views layer
    // Then start animating
    // But if the video is already ready to play, then we dont add it
    // This case comes up when the video has been cached like we have done so
    // and the cell is being reused
    if ([self.videoPlayer status] != AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
        [self.videoView.layer addSublayer:[self.indicator layer]];
        [self.indicator startAnimating];
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show this `[cell setVideo:vid];`?

Comment: Is the `dealloc` method of your `VideoCell` instances ever called? Do you properly cleanup the cell?

Comment: @anhtu i've added in that function

Comment: @rmaddy dealloc method of VideoCell is never called. How do I call it?

Comment: You don't call it. It should be called when the cell isn't needed any more. The fact that it isn't being called is a problem. You need to figure out why it isn't being called.

Comment: actually, it is being called sorry. in my tableview it draws 3 visible cells. then i push the button to pull data from the other API and the dealloc method is called. But its only called once, as opposed to 3 times